# Packaging Angular 5 UI-Components - Module not found

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, es6-modules

I'm developing UI Components for usage in different Web-Projects across the company. We want to publish the components as npm package on our local Repository, ideally with sources included (for debugging). I found [this article](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464) about exporting Angular Components and stick to it widely.

Unfortunately, when I npm install and import the package in another project, **the module is not found**:

```
import { TidUIComponentsModule } from '@tid/ui-components';
```

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(4,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@tid/ui-components'.

**Where should the (ES5/ES6/TS?) module be located in the npm package? And which configuration is required for this?**

---

My directory structure before packaging looks like this:

[image: directory structure before packaging]

With **package.json**:

```
{
   "name": "@tid/ui-components",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "main": "./bundles/tidcomponents.umd.js",
   "module": "./index.js",
   "typings": "./index.d.ts",
   "peerDependencies": {
      "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
      "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.6"
   },
   "license": "proprietary",
   "publishConfig": {
      "registry": "http://maven/repository/npm-internal/"
   },
   "files": [
      "dist"
   ]
}
```

**index.ts:**

```
export { TidUIComponentsModule } from './src/tid-ui-components.module';
export { ButtonComponent } from './src/components/button/button.component';
export { FormComponent } from './src/components/form/form.component';
export { FormRowComponent } from './src/components/form-row/form-row.component';
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
export default {
   input: 'dist/index.js',
   output: {
      format: 'umd',
      file: 'dist/bundles/tidcomponents.umd.js'
   },
   exports: 'named',
   sourceMap: false,
   name: 'tid.components',
   globals: {
      '@angular/core': 'ng.core',
      '@angular/common': 'ng.common',
      '@angular/forms': 'ng.forms',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'ngb.ng-bootstrap',
   },
   external: [
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/forms',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
   ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
      "@angular/common": ["node_modules/@angular/common"],
      "@angular/forms": ["node_modules/@angular/forms"],
      "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": ["node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"]
    },
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

After packaging it with `ngc && rollup -c && uglifyjs dist/bundles/tidcomponents.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments all --output dist/bundles/tidcomponents.umd.min.js`, this structure is created:

[image: directory structure after packaging]

After `npm install`, the folder in node_modules looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this import works:

```
import { TidUIComponentsModule } from '@tid/ui-components/dist';
```

Because that's where your `index` is located and your `bundles` folder. I believe changing your `package.json` would be enough:

Change your `main`, `module` and `typings` entries to:

```
"main": "./dist/bundles/tidcomponents.umd.js",
"module": "./dist/index.js",
"typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
```

You should also add some extra `angularCompilerOptions` to your `tsconfig.json`, and perhaps guide `ngc` to this config:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "index",
    "flatModuleId": "tid-components"
}
```

and package it using:

```
ngc -p ./tsconfig.json && rollup ... etc
```

Comment: The import now works pretty well!

But I stumbled upon another issue: when I use the tags like <tid-button>, the app compiles fine (although IntelliJ shows the error "Unknown HTML Tag") but in the browser, nothing is shown - the console says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found):4200/button.component.html`.

Do I have to change something (e.g. the target) in rollup.config or package.json to get the tags to work?

Comment: I guess the `ngc` compiler is not wrapping it into a nice bundle. Try adding the compilerOptions. I've updated my answer

Comment: Now the importing is broken again... index.d.ts is just `export * from './index';` and index.js `//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map`

Comment: I commented out some of the angularCompilerOptions and it works again. Unfortunately the error message is still the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655081/exporting-ui-components-in-angular-5-template-not-found

Comment: @fronteyes can you try to make the `main` in your `package.json` to equal: `"main": "./dist/index.js"`. If this works, it means your bundle is not being bundled ;)

Comment: When I try this, the output in tidcomponents.umd.js is
`(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory() :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
 (factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

/**
 * @fileoverview added by tsickle
 * @suppress {checkTypes} checked by tsc
 */

})));`

Doesn't seem right, does it?

Comment: True, so scratch that. A good reference is the [`angular-library-starter`](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-library-starter). Compare what you have with how it is done there, and read the readme carefully

Comment: In the meantime, I solved the problem by using ng-packagr: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e :) but tyvm for the help!

Comment: @fronteyes thanks! that looks like an interesting tool. Definitely going to try that out