# Exporting UI-Components in Angular 5 - template not found

Tags: angular, typescript, rollup

I'm developing UI Components for usage in different Web-Projects across the company. We want to publish the ui-components as npm package on our local Repository. Publishing the package [works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649905/packaging-angular-5-ui-components-module-not-found/47650051).

When I npm install the package, import the module in my `app.module.ts` and run 'ng serve' (it's an Angular CLI Project), everything compiles fine. But when accessing the Site on localhost, nothing is shown and the console says:

[image]

**Why is Angular looking for templates in html format, when they are compiled and packaged? And how to tell the CLI that these components are already compiled?**

---

**tsconfig.json** (before packaging)

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "declaration": true,
      "stripInternal": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "paths": {
         "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
         "@angular/common": ["node_modules/@angular/common"],
         "@angular/forms": ["node_modules/@angular/forms"],
         "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": ["node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"]
      },
      "rootDir": ".",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "lib": [
         "es2015",
         "dom"
      ]
   },
   "files": [
      "index.ts"
   ],
   "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "strictMetadataEmit": true
   }
}
```

*I was not able to find a documentation for the angularCompilerOptions on the Internet...*

The npm package in `node_modules` is:

[image]

---

I found the button-template by searching for CSS-Classes in `button.component.ngfactory.js` but the exported `ButtonComponentNgFactory` seems to be imported nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this to work, but another approach did work very well - it packed the template into different formats of JS and does all the work: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e